# How to assign a values to "cin>>variable" in command line

Tags: c++, shell, command-line

I am using Unix shell to run my C++ executable files. The program I am writing requires having some values assigned to its variables. I want to assign values to these variables on the command line rather than having a user manually entering them. In the following program, I was able to do that by providing two arguments in the command line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int apples, oranges;
    apples = stoi(argv[1]);
    oranges = stoi(argv[2]);
    cout << "Total Fruits: " << apples + oranges << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

However, if my program has a `cin>>` line as shown in the following program, how can I assign values to `apples` and `oranges` variables without the user having to manually enter these values. I would like to assign values to `cin>>apples` and `cin>>oranges` at the command line run (similar to: `program.exe 5 6`)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int apples, oranges;
    cin >> apples;
    cin >> oranges;
    cout << "Total Fruits: " << apples + oranges << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about `echo 5 6 | ./program`?

Comment: Tactical note:  Never use `argv` without first consulting `argc`.

Comment: You can use `apples = stoi(argv[1]);` to read from the command line (`e.g. myprog 5 6` ) or `cin >> apples;` to read from the user.  Q: So what exactly is your question?  Evg's solution, `echo 5 6 | ./program`, does *NOT* read from argc/argv: it reads from "stdin".  Which, maybe, is exactly what you're looking for?

Comment: @Evg Thank you for all of your comments. I am trying to execute this in a website using PHP. So, are you suggesting using something like this `shell_exec( '5 6' | './somepath/program');` This specific line didn't work for me. Maybe I need to modify this?

Comment: I guess you need `'echo 5 6 | ./somepath/program'`.

Comment: @DP. Another way you can use is to generalize your input routines to take data from a `std::istream &` variable (function parameter), take the `argv[x]` to a `std::istringstream` and pass it to your function with the `std::istream &` parameter. Thus you can choose if the input should be taken via `std::cin` or any other input stream.

Comment: @Evg Thank you so much for helping me out. Yes, that was the answer I was looking for. Much appreciated.